# Evaluating InterpolatingFunction returned by NDSolve is very slow starting from some arguments

Tags: performance-tuning, interpolation

I use this code to solve a PDE:

```
a = 20;
F[x_, t_] = f[x, t] /. First@NDSolve[{D[f[x, t], x, x] == I D[f[x, t], t],
     f[-a, t] == 0,
     f[a, t] == 0,
     f[x, 0] == Sin[Pi/a (x - a)]}, 
    f[x, t], {x, -a, a}, {t, 0, 700}, MaxStepSize -> 0.005 a]
```

It gives the correct solution for all `t` until about 650. But if I take `t` higher, see what happens:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[F[x, 650], {x, -a, a}];]
AbsoluteTiming[Table[F[x, 695.1], {x, -a, a}];]
```

> {0.000925, Null}
>
> {2.382157, Null}

Threshold for `t` appears to be about $666.6$.

It appears to be orders of magnitude slower at evaluating the interpolating function. What's the reason for this?

**EDIT**:

Using `NDSolve` option `InterpolationOrder -> All` works around this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening, but you can avoid it by recalculating the interpolation like this:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
a = 20; 
mdfun = First[f /. NDSolve[{D[f[x, t], x, x] == I D[f[x, t], t], f[-a, t] == 0, 
                           f[a, t] == 0, f[x, 0] == Sin[Pi/a (x - a)]}, 
                           f, {x, -a, a}, {t, 0, 700}, MaxStepSize -> 0.005 a]]; 
s = Transpose[{Flatten[InterpolatingFunctionGrid[mdfun], 1], 
               Chop /@ Flatten[InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[mdfun], 1]}];

q = Interpolation[s];
GraphicsRow@{Plot3D[Re@q[x, t], {x, -a, a}, {t, 0, 700}], 
             Plot3D[Im@q[x, t], {x, -a, a}, {t, 0, 700}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[Abs@q[x, t], {x, -a, a}, {t, 0, 700}, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]